On linear combination of polynomials in $k[X, Y]$
Suppose that $p(X,Y), f(X, Y)\in k[X, Y]$ where $p(X,Y)$ is irreducible and relatively prime to $f$. Can we always find $g(X,Y), h(X,Y)\in k[X, Y]$ such that $g(X,Y)p(X,Y)+h(X,Y)f(X,Y)$ is constant in either $X$ or $Y$?
This problem arises when I try to develop a proof for Bezout's theorem (i.e. $p$ and $f$ have only a finite number of common zeros). It seems to strong to be true, but I fail to find any counterexample. Can anyone help?

Yes, this is an application of Bezout's lemma (I guess Bezout must have proved this lemma in order to prove Bezout's theorem). First, by Gauss's lemma, $p$ remains irreducible over $K(x)[y]$, so $p$ and $f$ remain relatively prime over $K(x)[y]$. Happily $K(x)[y]$ is now a PID, so we can apply Bezout's lemma, which gives us $a, b \in K(x)[y]$ such that
$$ap + bf = 1.$$
Clearing denominators gives us $g, h \in K[x, y]$ such that $gp + hf \in K[x]$ as desired, and of course the same argument can be run for $K(y)[x]$. Maybe the resultant would give a sharper result but I'm not as familiar with it.

Thank you! I used to think that the proposition could not be true, so I did not try to prove it. It appears that I should not rely too much on my intuition since it is often inaccurate.

@zyy: in fact in order for Bezout's theorem to be true this statement must be true. Bezout's theorem together with the Nullstellensatz implies that if $p, f$ are relatively prime then the radical of the ideal $I(p, f) \subset K[x, y]$ they generate is the ideal of polynomials vanishing at finitely many points, so the radical necessarily contains both a polynomial in $x$ only (with roots the $x$-coordinates of the intersection) and a polynomial in $y$ only (with roots the $y$-coordinates of the intersection), hence so must $I(p, f)$.

(Of course I need to either assume that $K$ is algebraically closed or take the intersection over $\overline{K}$.)

Thank you for your detailed explanation.
